# How to get total price for product with qty before adding to cart in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, price, rules, grand-total

I have shopping cart promotion rules which gives discount for buying 4 products. This works fine on shopping cart page. I mean it applies discount and shows discounted price in TOTAL row. I want to show customer this discounted price on another page before he adds product to cart. How can I do it? Basically it is calculating price where product id and qty is given applying shopping cart price rules.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like code below, it should work correctly for tier prices and catalog price rules.

```
    /* @var $item Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item */
    $item = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item');
    $qty = 3;
    $product = /* load product you want to get price for */;
    $item->setProduct($product);
    $item->setQty($qty);
    $item->setQuote(/* get quote from checkout session */);
    $finalPrice = $product->getFinalPrice($item->getQty());
    $item->setPrice($finalPrice)
        ->setBaseOriginalPrice($finalPrice);
    $item->calcRowTotal();                

    $item->getRowTotal();
```